# CSV export customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I have the following piece of code which export a csv file.

```
  - if @product.type_id == 2
= "#{l(:user)} ID , #{l(:name)} , #{l(:company)} , #{l(:item)} , #{l(:total)} , #{l(:order_time_stamp)}"
- orders = @product.orders
- orders.each do |order|
  - order_users = get_user_who_order order
  - order_users.each do  |order_user|
    - user = order_user[:user]
    - products , op_total = get_products_and_total order_user[:order_products]
    - company = user.company.present?  ? user.company.name : ''
    - products = products.join('. ')
```

But we have list of items which is currently rendering in a single column however we need it to be in the different columns like item1, item2, item3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit crazy to me to do this with haml. There is a nice CSV library in Ruby you can use for this instead.

If you still insist on doing it with haml what you are missing is printing the extra `,` - you need to this yourself when using haml like this. I don't see any `=` in your loop at all. How is it possible that you get anything printed at all? (Except the header?)